# Setting up Concourse Pipeline for .NetFramework C# WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, concourse

Looking for a How-to document or sample Concourse CI Pipeline for use with a C# WCF Service using .NetFramework. Source is in Git. Build would use MSBuild. I don't see a lot of documentation or samples out there for this. Thanks!

Comment: Here's an example of someone using window (https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/greenhouse-ci/blob/0bdfa707e9bb2a75c7f1d7a6d2ec0ce1ef07fb69/bosh-windows-stemcell-builder/bosh-psmodules/task.yml#L2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put together a pipeline that mostly replicates a traditional  TFS build / Cruise Control type build.  Monitor sources, bump version, version assemblyinfo files, call msbuild for the application and Wix/MSI installer (versioning that also)  and then zip it all up and upload it to a custom API that I wrote that takes the zip and extracts it to a windows network share. I also send a slack message reporting the status.

On my servers I have a scheduled task that runs every 5 minutes monitoring the network share looking for updates and copying them to a cache and installing them when found.  Then it also sends a slack message.

So basically I have full CI/CD for my test environment.  I'm not doing a full "pipeline" with all kinds of integration into change request approvals and software distribution orchestration tools such as  Puppet or SCCM at this point.

Now it's possibly to skip the MSI and use an MSBuild publish profile in your project and just push your output directly to the server.  I'm not really a fan of that though as I'm an expert in Windows Installer and can create very complex solutions that install everything on the baremetal and handle a variety of situtations not just sync the latest changes in.  But maybe you prefer that approach instead.

I don't know if I can share this code yet but if I can it'll be posted as an open source project.  I'm going to be honest though,  I'm not fully convinced that Concourse CI is the right tool for this job.  I'd rather be using Visual Studio Team Services Build and Release pipelines.  Unfortunatly I don't really have much say in them matter anymore so I'm trying to make the best of it.

Comment: Thanks Christopher Painter. Your answer in itself, pretty much tells me what I've been experiencing myself. (It's a little early for Concourse CI for C# .Net Framework).

Comment: It's possible and there are some things I like about it.  But it is a bit like trying to shove a square peg into a round hole and then being looked at like your stupid for not using a round peg because clearly pipelines are round not square.  I once asked if concourse supported windows containers and was told that all docker containers are Linux containers.  I then offended said person by disagreeing and now I don't get a single reply when I ask new questions.  Good times... :)